# assert invalid, misplaced or occurs too often

Tags: xml, testing, xsd, assert

i'm coming accross with this error whilst trying to generate my XSD and can't figure out what i'm doing wrong; my code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="FICH">
<xs:complexType>

<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="cabeza">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="VERSION_ORIG" type="Version"/>

</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="DATA_MAJ">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="DATA1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>

<xs:element name="VERSION_SIT_NOM" type="Version"/>

</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>

<xs:assert test="CABEZA/VERSION_ORIG = DATA_MAJ/VERSION_SIT_NOM"/>

</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="YYMM">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}[01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12]"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Version">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="emptyString">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value=""/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

the idea is that element CABEZA/VERSION_ORIG has to be equal than DATA_MAJ/VERSION_SIT_NOM. I've search for some solutions but everything seems OK for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really know why stackoverflow deleted the part when i say hello to everyone in the message, anyways.. just say that the error is bouncing because of the assert clause

Comment: Welcome to SO; [This is how/why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) the salutation gets removed. It is worthwhile to familiarize yourself with how things work on SO. There are some tips on what a good question is; I would say, based on what I've seen before, that you were lucky not to get downvoted... For e.g., you're not saying anything about what you've used to get the error message, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema document looks OK to me (and more to the point, also to Saxon 9).

So the most probable cause of your error message is (1) that you are using an XSD 1.0 processor to process an XSD 1.1 schema document, and (2) that your processor does not provide the world's best error messages in this case.  At this time (early 2013) XSD 1.1 is supported by Saxon and by a beta release of Xerces J.  If you're using another XSD validator, you might want to contact the vendor or developer to ask them when they will support XSD 1.1.  (No one will move to 1.1 if they think their users don't care.)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a couple of things wrong. Let's start with a corrected XSD and matching sample XML.

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:tns="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="FICH">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="cabeza">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="VERSION_ORIG" type="Version"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DATA_MAJ">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="DATA1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="VERSION_SIT_NOM" type="Version"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>          
            <xs:assert test="tns:cabeza/tns:VERSION_ORIG = tns:DATA_MAJ/tns:DATA1/tns:VERSION_SIT_NOM"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="YYMM">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}[01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="Version">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="emptyString">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value=""/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Invalid XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<FICH xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">
    <cabeza>
        <VERSION_ORIG>22.22.22</VERSION_ORIG>
    </cabeza>
    <DATA_MAJ>
        <DATA1>
            <VERSION_SIT_NOM>22.22.23</VERSION_SIT_NOM>
        </DATA1>
    </DATA_MAJ>
</FICH>
```

**Error message:**

```
Error while loading [], line 12 position 8
cvc-assertion.3.13.4.1: Assertion evaluation ('tns:cabeza/tns:VERSION_ORIG = tns:DATA_MAJ/tns:DATA1/tns:VERSION_SIT_NOM') for element 'FICH' with type '#anonymous' did not succeed. 
Document1.xml is XSD 1.1 invalid.
```

Explanations:

- Most likely you're using an XSD 1.0 processor to validate an XSD 1.1. Comment out the assert and see if the error goes away.
- Unless your XSD has no target namespace, you have to provide an alias, such as xmlns:tns in my sample XSD above, to match your target namespace; make sure that the XPath uses prefixes appropriately. There are reasons why, and Xerces (as mentioned by @CMSperbergMcQueen) seems to want them badly, too.
- You've got the XPath all wrong. Names are case sensitive, so cabeza is not CABEZA, plus you've got an extra level in your XSD that is not matched by your XPath; more specifically, you're missing a DATA1.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, the case sensitive problems were solved as i copied a part of my schema because it's very long and i messed up copying cabeza; as you said i think is more a problem of processor than the xsd itself as i get no errors zhen i comment the assert.

Comment: ... and moreover copying your example i'm still having problems with the assert.. Getting to this point it seems very confusing to me because i'm using "XML Notepad 2007 Version 2.5" to validate that supports 1.1, i also tried adding the alias like in your example but as i said even your example bounces the same error for me. Anyways i'll keep racking my brain..

Comment: @nes.abra, the XSD that I've provided is valid, so you can take it up with the support team for the XML Notepad. If the product you're referring to is the one Microsoft put out a while ago, then forget about it and XSD 1.1. The only free XSD 1.1 processor, albeit a beta version, is Xerces; download it and play with that one instead (using the command line or maybe you can ask around is there's a UI supporting it). I am sure that if you download eval versions of various XSD editors in the market one after another, it can keep you going for a couple of months, to do whatever you need.